# Как выбрать из div все картинки и отправить обработчиком ajax

Tags: javascript, html, php

Ребят, есть ситуация такая:

Есть блок с картинками и есть textarea, где пользователь вводит текст, при нажатии на кнопку нужно, чтоб я брал и текст, и картинки вместе и заносил это всё БД.

Вот такая задача. )

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что это работа за автора

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрипт не тестил, может, есть ошибки=))

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['img']) and isset($_POST['text'])){
    $img = $_POST['img'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $query = 'INSERT INTO my_table (img,text) VALUES ($img,$text)';
    $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
    exit(json_encode($res));
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(
        img = $('#img').html();
        text = $('#textarea').val();
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://site.ru/save_inf.php',
            data: 'img='+img+'&text='+text,
            success: function(jsondata){
              console.log(jsondata);
            },dataType: "json"});
    ));
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="img">
  <img src="img.gif"/>
  <img src="img.gif"/>
  <img src="img.gif"/>
</div>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<a href="#" id="button">Отправить</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: и всё, что ль? :D так легко? :D, прям три картинки и уйдёт в базу?

Comment: А что вам ещё нужно? Как спросили, так и ответил :D

Comment: да я думал, там гемор такой:D

Comment: Ну если верный ответ, то ставте+ :D

Comment: конечно, поставлю)) можешь ещё подсказать, как в загрузчики поставить минимальный размер файла?)

Comment: ))Скрипт. написанные выше, не загружает картинки, а только берёт их HTML код, если нужна загрузка, то почитайте про ajaxupload jquery или можно вместо простой Textarea использовать CKEDITOR(http://ckeditor.com/) + kcfinder (http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/), оно и текст редактирует, и картинки загружает на сервер.